# How can I populate more than one Silverlight Image from Bing Maps asynchronous calls?

Tags: image, silverlight, asynchronous, bing-maps

I have the following code, which works fine if you just want to populate one Image with a response from Bing Maps. But if I try to do two then the variable _currentImage always ends up being "image1" because the calls are asynchronous. How can I pass the image variable along to the ImageryServiceGetMapUriCompleted method?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using BasicBingMapsImagerySvc.ImageryService;

namespace BasicBingMapsImagerySvc
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private const string BingMapsKey = "my key";

        private Image _currentImage;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetMap(42.573377, -101.032251, image0, MapStyle.AerialWithLabels);

            GetMap(42.573377, -101.032251, image1, MapStyle.Road_v1);
        }


        private void GetMap(double lat, double lon, Image image, MapStyle mapStyle)
        {
            var mapUriRequest = new MapUriRequest();

            // Set credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
            mapUriRequest.Credentials = new Credentials();
            mapUriRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = BingMapsKey;

            // Set the location of the requested image
            mapUriRequest.Center = new Location();
            mapUriRequest.Center.Latitude = lat;
            mapUriRequest.Center.Longitude = lon;

            // Set the map style and zoom level
            var mapUriOptions = new MapUriOptions();
            mapUriOptions.Style = mapStyle;
            mapUriOptions.ZoomLevel = 13;

            // Set the size of the requested image to match the size of the image control
            mapUriOptions.ImageSize = new SizeOfint();
            mapUriOptions.ImageSize.Height = 256;
            mapUriOptions.ImageSize.Width = 256;

            mapUriRequest.Options = mapUriOptions;

            var imageryService = new ImageryServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IImageryService");
            imageryService.GetMapUriCompleted += ImageryServiceGetMapUriCompleted;

            _currentImage = image;

            imageryService.GetMapUriAsync(mapUriRequest);


        }

        private void ImageryServiceGetMapUriCompleted(object sender, GetMapUriCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // The result is an MapUriResponse Object
            MapUriResponse mapUriResponse = e.Result;
            var bmpImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri(mapUriResponse.Uri));

            _currentImage.Source = bmpImg;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lambda expression / delegate for your event handler, which allows you to 'capture' the reference to the image:

```
  var imageryService = new ImageryServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IImageryService");
  imageryService.GetMapUriCompleted += (s,e) =>
     {
         // The result is an MapUriResponse Object
         MapUriResponse mapUriResponse = e.Result;
         var bmpImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri(mapUriResponse.Uri));

         // set the image source
         image.Source = bmpImg;
    };
```

Comment: Colin, you're awesome! Thanks. I was trying to get there on my own but couldn't figure out the lambda syntax.